# SVG text background image problems

Tags: jquery, html, svg

So I'm designing a photo frame designer. You can find it [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2). I want when one of the patterns (under the solid blocks of colour under text design) is clicked the text on the frame changes to have its background as that pattern's image. I understand that SVG uses the fill attribute and you need to make it into a pattern. It definitely does something at the minute. I want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xWNR3/98/) this but I need it to be able to be called on click.

Here is my code. You can find the full code on my website though.

```
    <defs>                              
        <pattern id="patt1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1246" height="1000">
            <image xlink:href="Images/pattern1.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1247" height="751" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <text class="text" transform="matrix(2.4428 0 0 1.5 624.6 550.5599)" font-family="'ComicSansMS'" font-size="41.6368">Your words here</text>
```

and this

```
$("#pattern1").click (function() {
    $('.text').css('fill', 'url(#patt1)');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you wrap your code with `$(document).ready`?

Comment: So what's the problem/question?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work.